# What are advantages of using servlets when building rest api in java

Tags: java, rest, servlets, grizzly, undertow

I have been working on several projects (and some of them were quite big) where we always used grizzly2-http server + jersey for building rest api and  we never had any problems. Now, I have been looking at some other options to make sure I am not missing some big improvement and I like undertow but it is based on servlets and I didn't used them before and I do not see it in the list of jersey containers (https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/containers although I am sure there it can be used somehow). My question is what are advantages of implementing rest api using servlets?

I have found a lot of answers what are servlets and what they do but it looks to me like everyone is just using servlets and that is some kind of convention, no one is really listing advantages over "containerless" (this is only term I could find). Is there some security, performance advantage?

Comment: Servlets are the de-facto standard in Java for building HTTP services, so most things are built on top of servlets because servlets are ubiquitous (and that includes Jersey).

Answer (score 0):

**This question is more experimental so everyone might have different answers/opinion based on his/her knowledge.**

*Personally I think these are some reasons why you should consider Servlet when you decide to write a REST application:*

- Java has lots of great security libraries (ex: Spring Security) that could configure and sit together with the Servlet filters to control all of your requests efficiently
- JSON Serialization and Deserialization is easy when using java because of libraries like gson, jackson
- It's easy to follow right ways of modularity while coding in Java because Java Enterprise stack is very appropriate for creating MVC and N-Tier application
- You can integrate lots of great enterprise libraries with your REST data within Java application because of great Java open-source projects (ex: Kafka, hadoop, etc)
- Most of the could platforms are having a java client libraries in most of their services so it is good to have your REST code written in Java because later you might need to shift in one of those clouds and as your project grow bigger, you don't need to be worry how to connect to those platforms (in your backend part)

> When you are writing a big scale project, there are many reasons for
>   choosing certain technology. Maybe the technology task is only one of
>   those concerns. You have to predict where your project will go in the
>   future and based on that decide to select the best existing solution.